# Does WCF have an equivalent of MVC's [Authorize] attribute?

Tags: .net, wcf

I want to decorate certain Operation Contracts with an attribute to authorize the caller by custom logic, something like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior]
public class Service1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [Authorize] // ?? this should make sure only admins can call this method
    public List<SampleItem> GetCollection()
    {
        return new List<SampleItem>() { new SampleItem("Only Admins see me") };
    }
}
```

The [Authorize] should check if the caller is entitled to call this operation; if not - it should return an error fault.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not out of the box - but WCF top-guru Juval Löwy had a very interesting article in MSDN Magazine about [Declarative WCF Security](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/A/7/3A7FA450-1F33-41F7-9E6D-3AA95B5A6AEA/MSDNMagazineAugust2007en-us.chm) which goes in the same direction.

Juval identified several key security scenarios, and wrapped each of them up into a WCF service behavior to be applied as an attribute on your service class on the server side. Quite an interesting read indeed !

Comment: Not only is this a good answer, but you're so close to 100k that you deserve an upvote. Rock on!

Comment: " In this column, I present my declarative security framework." - great read.

Comment: In sum for your questions the article basically wants you to use:  [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = @"WindowsRole or CustomRoleName")] Additionally: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647503.aspx

Comment: I couldn't read any of the content with Windows 10 HTML Help. Solved it by following these steps: "[...] On most versions of windows you must first save these files to your local machine, and then unblock the file in order to read it. To unblock a file, right click on it, and select properties, and then select the ‘unblock’ button. The content will then be available to read." —[MSDN Magazine Issues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/msdn-magazine-issues.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

WCF doesn't have any special attribute for this purpose but you can use PrincipalPermissionAttribute - common approach for declarative role-based security in .NET.

Answer (score 2):

In my WCF application, I've largely overrided all the default authentication and authorization stuff, and I use some custom processing of the `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` to check my custom security permissions.

I have some code snippits of how I did this in this post: [.NET Declarative Security: Why is SecurityAction.Deny impossible to work with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092817/net-declarative-security-why-is-securityaction-deny-impossible-to-work-with)